# Firebase conversion postback to custom ad network

Tags: firebase, postback

We are implementing Firebase in our application. I know Firebase supports postback to some ad networks; but the point is we have our own local ad network which is not popular so it's not listed in the menu where you select ad networks.

**Is it possible in Firebase to send conversion data to custom ad network?** (something like S2S postback)

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to have Firebase automatically post conversion data to ad networks that aren't listed in that menu.

That said, please go ahead and nominate your favorite network through Google's [application form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScO5ilst9vqZ8uzJCWbGJWWcCWN69zclSn1xg2CsbwGPqNjtg/viewform) and the team can look into adding them to the list.

Comment: this would be a great feature to have